# Can't access this webpage

Tags: python, html, parsing, url, urlopen

I am trying to write a python parser for this website 'http://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2015#sorting=rank+region=+country=+faculty=+stars=false+search='

Every time I do the regular urlopen and print it, it says
'Access denied | www.topuniversities.com used CloudFlare to restrict access'.

After I tried this method

```
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
url = 'http://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university rankings/2015#sorting=rank+region=+country=+faculty=+stars=false+search='
myopener = MyOpener()
page = myopener.open(url).read()
print page
```

But this prints out something other then what my chrome's inspect elements shows. I need to parse the names of the universities their rankings and the url that leads to their page.
What do I do? Please Help

Comment: Is your URL correct? Seems like you are missing `-` from `world-university rankings`

Comment: If I were I would use `selenium` with `webdriver`.